# Angular 7 - Labels and Date values

Tags: arrays, angular, object, chart.js

i have an issue:
This is my errorsList:

```
{labels: Array(2), values: Array(2)}
labels: (2) ["sales-be", "sales-mw"]
values: (2) [48, 8]
```

In this.ChartyData i want to put as label all the label of that json errorsList.

```
this.ChartyData = [
      {
        data: this.errorsList.values,
        label: this.errorsList.labels,
        fill: false,
      },
    ];
```

When i put:

```
label: this.errorsList.labels,
```

It groups all the labels in errorsList. I want them to be separated and not all grouped.

Here in this image you can see that. I want the rectangles to be like in pie chart, but in line chart he groups that values. How can i separate them??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in line chart it puts header(label) for each line.
if you want to separate the labels you need to do some lines.
each object in the array in a line.

```
this.ChartyData = [
      { data: ..., label: ...},  { data: ..., label: ...}
];
```